# perl shutdown a socket

Tags: perl, sockets

Is there a difference between

```
shutdown($socket, 0) if $socket;
shutdown($socket, 2) if $socket;
close($socket) if $socket;
```

and

```
shutdown($socket, 2) if $socket;
close($socket) if $socket;
```

Also is there a difference between

```
shutdown($socket, 1) if $socket;
shutdown($socket, 2) if $socket;
close($socket) if $socket;
```

and

```
shutdown($socket, 2) if $socket;
close($socket) if $socket;
```

And finally is the `close` needed at all?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`shutdown`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/shutdown.2.html) causes one side of the TCP connection to stop reading (`0`), or writing (`1`), or both (`2`). So the first two snippets have the same effect, as do the next two.

`shutdown` does not release the file descriptor, so [`close`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/close.2.html) is still needed.

The difference between single `close` and one preceded by `shutdown( fd, 2 )` is that in the second case TCP will not try to deliver outstanding data to the remote side (see [`SO_LINGER`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/socket.7.html)).

Comment: I'm getting  an unexpected error. `$rc = shutdown($socket, 1);` returns `1` as expected (no error). If I follow this by `$rc = shutdown($socket, 0);` it returns `0` and `%!` is `Transport endpoint is not connected`  which is not what I expect. If I follow this by `close` it appears to throw and prematurely exit the script. So this seems very strange to me.